# JS to change link based on screen size

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, hyperlink

we have a website which uses modals and we would like to give mobile users access to the content of the modal without loading it in a modal.

Is there any way to detect the resolution of a screen and display a different link to these users?

Thanks

Comment: `if (screen.height > 1000) element.src = '/myotherpage.html'`

Comment: if you're developing your website in Adobe Dreamweaver, you could check out "Fluid Grid Layout". it is available in Adobe DW CS6 only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I noticed you added jQuery tag. You could use jQuery to get screen dimensions:

```
var width = $(window).width();
var height = $(window).height();
```

Then change the link by doing what adeneo have suggested in the comment